# Weird reflections, as if stretched models

Tags: materials, reflection

I'm trying to make a chess board, and with the pawns I've added, the black marble squares seem to reflect the white pawns as if they're taller - i.e. they seem to be reflecting "ghost" images of tall white pawns, as opposed to the pawns' actual size, so in the attached picture the black squares at the bottom left of the image reflect the pawns at the top left of the image, even though I wouldn't expect them to. This applies from different angles, moving around the scene - the white pawns are reflected as if they're super-tall.

I've tried applying all scales (in object mode I press 'a', then 'ctrl + a' -> scale) which seemed to be the obvious thing but this doesn't make a difference. I've no idea what's going on or whether it's to do with the marble texture reflecting incorrectly or the pawn model somehow appearing different when reflected - any help appreciated!

Context: Newbie here, this is my first attempt at a render that's not a tutorial.

The *.blend file is attached - note that I had to remove the wooden board, the white squares and the black pawns to get under the upload size limit, but I do still see the undesired reflections in this simplified file.

[image]

[image: render of .blend file]

Comment: Issue is caused by Normal map node if you unplug it it is fine. To use normal map texture you have to switch color space of the Image node from sRGB to **Non-Colour** type ... btw the Normal texture is empty so I don't see a reason to use it at all :)

Comment: That worked a charm @vklidu - thanks very much!